# Error al instalar Jekyll: "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, cmd

Hace una semana estaba tranquilo usando jekyll.. solo tuve que instalar Ruby y Ruby on rails.. hace 2 o 3 dias mi Windows 10 se actualizo solo y por alguna razon desde ahora cada vez que trato de instalar Jekyll me sale:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
>   Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   ...
>
> current directory: C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
>   make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> "make" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> current directory: C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
>   make "DESTDIR="
>   "make" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>
> make failed, exit code 1
>   ...

Ya probé lo siguiente:

- Reinstalar Ruby y rails, luego en otro cmd prompt intentar
- Instalar Jekyll y ruby devkit con Ubuntu (siguiedo los pasos en https://jekyllrb.com)
- Instalar Jekyll y ruby devkit desde Bash. Mismo error
- Instalar Jekyll y ruby devkit con Chocolatey (siguiedo los pasos en https://jekyllrb.com)

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema es por la incompatibilidad de la versión de RubyGems con las gemas de extensión nativa.

En otro hilo probaron el siguiente código

```
gem update --system 2.3.0
```

Fuente: [Native gem installation](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977)